# JsonView ignore all but annotated properties

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, json-view

I have the following `JsonView` configuration:

```
public class JsonViews {

    public static class AdminView {
    }

    public static class PublicView extends AdminView {
    }
}
```

I have the following entity:

```
public class UserEntity {

    @JsonView(JsonViews.AdminView.class)
    private int id;

    @JsonView(JsonViews.PublicView.class)
    private int name;

    // getters / setters
}
```

In my controller I have the following methods:

- I want this method to return ALL properties

  ```
  @JsonView(JsonViews.AdminView.class)
  public List<User> getAllOnlyForAdmin { return foo; }
  ```
- I want this to return ONLY the name property

  ```
  @JsonView(JsonViews.PublicView.class)
  public List<User> getAllOnlyForAdmin { return foo; }
  ```

Possible? If not, is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you have just a single view for the *name-only* case;

```
public class JsonViews {

    public static class NameView {
    }
}
```

and the entity;

```
public class UserEntity {

    private int id;

    @JsonView(JsonViews.NameView.class)
    private int name;

    // getters / setters
}
```

and controller methods;

```
@JsonView(JsonViews.NameView.class)
@RequestMapping("/admin/users")
public List<User> getUsersWithOnlyName() {
    return userGetter.getUsers();
}
```

will get you only name field for every `User`, and

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userGetter.getUsers();
}
```

will get you the whole entity, the default behaviour.

---

More on `@JsonView` on `Spring` [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) under topic *6. Using JSON Views with Spring*, also on [spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)